# Finding the actual url/path of a file from its apparent url

Tags: php, file, curl, attachment

I am trying to create a copy of a file which is located on a remote server to my server through some php code using curl....The problem is, the file resides at a url similar to this http://www.xyz.com/file.aspx...So when this url is used/clicked, it prompts for a download of the .txt file which is exactly the file i am trying to create a copy of....The url explicitly doesnt give out the filename...
It only prompts for the .txt file when clicked...So is there a way to find out the file this url is pointing to through some php code?..Thanks in advance...

-pcup

Comment: One "." per sentence is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The aspx file is probably outputting headers that tell your browser the name of the file that it's about to transmit, then sends the contents of the file. I often do this with PHP code to return pdf files:

```
$filename = "/path/on/server/to/file.pdf";
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . '"' . basename($filename) . '"' . ";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
set_time_limit(0);
readfile($filename);
```

When you make your curl request to the aspx page, check the headers that are returned by the server to determine the actual filename of the file that is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you do 'curl ' on the command line, do you get the file you want? The CURL lib in PHP should do the same...you don't need to know the name of the file if you know the URL to GET to cause the server to send you the file.

Comment: Exactly...I dont need the name of the file...I just want a copy of it. The reason for me to ask if finding its path was possible was because it would have done my job much easier..Any alternatives are welcome too...

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not "pointing" anywhere.  The URL is the one you typed in.

The server is setting the [content-disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) MIME header.  You can access it via Curl by setting the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option with `curl_setopt()`.